# should 投げ槍 be used or 投げ遣り？

Tags: meaning, usage

I'm confused at the use of 投げ槍 here. There are definitely no javelins/spears in this scene, so wouldn't 投げ遣り be correct?

> アクアの、面倒臭そうな**投げ槍**なその態度に、流石に俺もカチンときた。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This なげやり clearly means *perfunctory*, *indifferent*, *irresponsible*, etc. デジタル大辞泉 explicitly says using the kanji 投げ槍 in this sense is wrong. (But this also means 投げ槍 is a very common mistake even among native speakers.)

> #### [投げ遣り](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/163803/meaning/m0u/%E6%8A%95%E3%81%92%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A/)
>
> ［名・形動］物事をいいかげんに行うこと。成り行きまかせにすること。また、そのさま。「投げ遣りな態度」「商売を投げ遣りにする」
>   **[補説]この意味で「投げ槍」と書くのは誤り。**
>
> #### [投げ槍](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/163802/meaning/m0u/%E6%8A%95%E3%81%92%E6%A7%8D/)
>
> 敵に投げつけるために用いる柄の短い槍。

When in doubt, use hiragana, which is always safe :)

Comment: nice! I think this is the first time I've found a mistake in a Japanese book.